# typedb.common.exception.TypeDBClientException: [QRY16] Invalid Query Pattern

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql, reactql

When i am trying to fetch count. getting this below error

``` ``[QRY16] Invalid Query Pattern: The pattern '{{ $xy isa taggedwith; $xy ($x, $y);  $x has $_0; $x isa Person;  $y isa Employer;  $_0 = "ab333a1a-0688-4d70-a9da-32b095a69223"; $_0 isa unique_id; }}' can never be satisfied the current schema, specifically due to '[{ $xy isa taggedwith; $xy ($x, $y);  $x has $_0; $x isa Person;  $y isa Employer;  $_0 = "ab333a1a-0688-4d70-a9da-32b095a69223"; $_0 isa unique_id; }]'. ```

Please check server logs for the stack trace`.`

Actual Query i am using:

**`match $x isa Person; {$x  id ab333a1a-0688-4d70-a9da-32b095a69223;}; $xy ($x, $y) isa taggedwith; $y isa Employer; get $y; count;`**

I want to fetch count, without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you've written a query that is not semantically valid according to your schema. For example, it's possible that a `Person` or an `Employer` cannot be part of a  `taggedwith` relation, which means this query will never find any results.

The best way to debug this error is to partition your query into smaller parts that are not invalid, then add the pieces back one by one until you find the part of the query that causes the error.

Also, it looks like the `id` keyword should not be valid. There is a TypeQL keyword (in version 2.8.0) called `iid` but it requires a hex input, such as `$x iid 0x123...`. If `id` is an attribute you have created on `Person`, you'll want to use `$x has id "ab333a1a-0688-4d70-a9da-32b095a69223"` as a string attribute.

Hope this helps!